# Sum of digits of sum of digits of sum of digits of $7^{7^{7^7}}$

Tags: number-theory, big-numbers

On the back of a mathematical magazine, I came across some "quick facts" about the number 7. Most of them were real life related ones, like "Rome was buit on 7 hills", "the neck of most mamals is made out of 7 bones", "a ladybird has 7 black spots on its back" etc.

But the last one was very intriguing: denote by $A$ the sum of digits of the number $7^{7^{7^7}}$, by $B$ the sum of digits of $A$, and by $C$ the sum of digits of $B$. What is the sum of digits of $C$?

After doing some research on the power of usual computers, I concluded that it would not be possible to calculculate this number and find the sums like this. So the solution must be pure mathematical. But I could not manage to find any path to a solution. If it helps, we have that $7^7=823543$ which has sum of digits $25$, but online big number calculators can't even compute $7^{7^7}$, and I figured it was not worth it to write such a program myself.

---

**Edit**: After some good hours I want to draw some conclusions about the question as well as proposing some extensions.

We saw that for the proposed number $^4 7$, the searched sum is $7$. Mees de Vries found a rigorous proof for that, but which doesn't seem to work in a general case; Henry gave a quite tedious solution which may be generalizable with some extra explanations needed, and Gottfried Helms came up with a computer algorithm which he used to deduce that the sum of digits (repeated as many times as necessary) will repeat with period 3 across consecutive powers of 7.

Now, based on the fact that from Euler's Theorem we will get that $^n 7$ has residue $7$ mod 9, for any $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$, I came to believe that if we repeatedly do sum of digits for larger $^n 7$ we will also get 7. The question is  how many times we would have to do the sum-of-digits. Also, I would like to notice that the number 7 here is not a simple coincidence. It is because it is $\varphi(9)+1$, and the sum-of-digits conserves mod 9. It would be interesting to find a similar property for 3, which has totient function 2, and also "conserves" the residue of the sum-of-digits (here it seems that the sum will be 9 - at least this is how it is for $3^3$ and $3^{3^3}$).

Thanks for all your answers!

Comment: I am almost certain the proof is going to come down to the fact that applying the sum-of-digits operation to ${}^47$ four times is going to result in a 1-digit number, so the answer is just the positive single-digit equivalent mod 9. But it is hard to prove because the sum-of-digits operation isn't very well-behaved.

Comment: Also it is pretty hard just to find the residue mod 9 of that number

Comment: [No, that would definitely be the easy part.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7%5E(7%5E(7%5E7))+mod+9)

Comment: Alright, now I really expect the answer to be 7 or something similar

Comment: apropos "big numbers" - have you tried Robert Munafo's "hypercalc"? It can do some nice things with really large numbers... (see http://mrob.com/pub/comp/hypercalc/hypercalc-javascript.html)

Comment: You can use Pari/GP to work with numbers like $7^{7^7}$, for instance $7^{7^7}*\log(7)/\log(10)$ gives you the number of digits of $\;^47$ in a couple of seconds (displaying its twenty leading digits) - you might even let it show you the first 10000 digits of that number-of-digits.

Comment: Interestingly, since that following numbers are directly managable, we can determine $A,B,C$ for the initial values $Z=\;^37 = 7^{7^7}$ arriving at $C=7$ as well as for $Z= 7^{7^2},Z= 7^{7^3},Z= 7^{7^4},Z= 7^{7^5},Z= 7^{7^6},...$ Can we do some induction-step from this?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I have tried it. It gives me an approximation of it. For the other comment. How did you work out A,B,C for those? Are you saying that $C=7$ for any $7^{7^x}$?

Comment: @AndreiCataron - yes, this seemed to the case simply using non-recursive sum-of-digits applied to $Z_k=7^{7^k}$ three times.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms - Since there is no nondigit number equal to the sum of its digits, we will have that is we apply tge sum-if digits to any number of form $7^{7N}$ (in your case $N=7^{k-1}$) sufficiently many times we will get 7. The question remains hiw many iterations are required.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let $\mathrm{sod}$ stand for the upper-bounded sum-of-digits operation, that is, 
$$
\mathrm{sod}(n) = \sup_{m \leq n}\left( \text{sum of digits of $m$}\right).
$$
This has the nice advantage that it is trivially a monotone function.

If we can prove that
$$
\mathrm{sod}^4\left(7^{7^{7^7}}\right) < 10,
$$
we can use [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) to quickly conclude, because applying the (ordinary) sum of digits operation does not change the residue modulo 9. But let's let WolframAlpha do the work for us, to see that [the result will be 7](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7%5E(7%5E(7%5E7))+mod+9).

Note that $\mathrm{sod}(n) \leq 9(\log_{10}(n) + 1)$, as $\log_{10}(n) + 1$ is an upper bound on the number of digits in the number $n$, and each digit is at most 9. Let's focus on the case where $n$ has at least two digits, so that in fact this is upper bounded by $18\log_{10}(n)$. Then we have that
$$
\mathrm{sod}^4\left(7^{7^{7^7}}\right) \leq \mathrm{sod}^3\left(7^{7^7} \cdot 18 \cdot \log_{10}(7)\right) \leq \mathrm{sod}^2\left(7^7\cdot 18 \cdot \log_{10}(7) + 18\log_{10}(18) + 18\log_{10}^2(7)\right).
$$
(Note that we are using the monotonicity of our $\mathrm{sod}$ function here! This is why we made the definition.)

The number in the argument of $\mathrm{sod}^2$ is small enough that we can just evaluate it for simplicity: it is certainly upper bounded by 12527573. The $\mathrm{sod}$ of this number is the sum of digits of $9999999$, which is $7 \times 9 = 63$, and we are left just barely (!) able to conclude, because the $\mathrm{sod}$ of this number is the sum of digits of $59$, which is $14$. Despite the fact that this is larger than the 10 we claimed we needed above, we are still done: if the sum of digits we were after were greater than 7 it would have to be at least 16, and it cannot be, thus we conclude that the result is indeed 7.

Comment: This is pretty amazing. How did you come across the sod function?

Comment: I made it up -- I needed something that would upper bound the sum-of-digits operation while still being monotone (because when you can't use arguments of the form $a \leq b \implies \mathrm{sod}(a) \leq \mathrm{sod}(b)$ the proof falls apart).

Comment: Going straight to the $18\log_{10}(n)$ would have worked for the first part of the proof, but it wouldn't have been tight enough for the correct conclusion.

Comment: I was wondering if larger numbers like $^5 7$ would still have the quadruple (or quintuple) sum 7, since the residue mod 9 is still 7. I tried you method, but if you apply the inequality $\text{sod}(n)\leq 18\log_{10} n$ too many times, you won't be able able to compute the result anymore, since you will have the logarithm of a sum after 3 steps.

Comment: @AndreiCataron, it's hard to exactly compute the logarithm of a sum when you can't compute the sum directly, but if you can find a pretty tight upper bound on the sum -- note that two of the summands will be astronomically small compared to the third -- then you can continue with that. This whole argument uses pretty wide upper bounds (in particular the $18\log_{10}(n)$ is far larger than necessary) so a weaker upper bound would probably still function.

Comment: The good thing with the logarithm is that it reduces the biggest number to calculate. On the other hand, if we use something like $\log_{10} n\leq \frac{n}{6}$, we won't have something much easier to calculate.

Answer (score 8):

- $7^{3n}\equiv 1 \pmod 9$, $7^{3n+1}\equiv 7 \pmod 9$, $7^{3n+2}\equiv 4 \pmod 9$
- $7^{m}\equiv 1 \pmod 3$

  - so $7^{7^{7^7}} \equiv 7 \pmod 9$ and is of the form $9k+7$ for some $k$
- any number less than $17$ (actually $79$) of the form $9k+7$ has a digit sum of $7$

  - $7 \lt 10$
- any number less than $10^{10}+7$ (actually $8\times 10^{72}-1$) of the form $9k+7$ has a digit double sum of $7$

  - $7^7 \lt 10^{10}$
- any number less than $10^{10^{10}}+7$ (actually $8 \times 10^{8\times 10^{72}-8} -1$) of the form $9k+7$ has a digit triple sum of $7$

  - $7^{7^7} \lt 10^{10^{10}}$
- any number less than $10^{10^{10^{10}}}+7$ (actually $8\times 10^{8 \times 10^{8\times 10^{72}-8} -8}-1$) of the form $9k+7$ has a digit quadruple sum of $7$

  - $7^{7^{7^7}} \lt 10^{10^{10^{10}}}$

So $7^{7^{7^7}}$ has a digit quadruple sum of $7$

Answer (score 2):

I propose the following definition for the (recursive) sum-of-digits function

```
  \\ Pari/GP-Code     
  {sod(n) = local(s,d);
     while(n>9, 
           s=0; while(n>0,
                    d=n % 10;  \\ the last digit to "d"
                    s=s+d;     \\ add "d" to the digit-sum "s"
                    n=n\10;   \\ shift n one decimal digit to the right
                    );    \\ s has now the number of digits of n,
           n=s);  \\ because possibly s>9 we use this as new n and repeat  
      return(n);}
```

If we check now the sum-of-digits of consecutive powers of $7$ we get

```
vector(12,r,sod(7^(r-1 )))
 %969 = [1, 7, 4, 1, 7, 4, 1, 7, 4, 1, 7, 4]
```

and we see, that this is simply periodic with period $3$

```
vector(12,r,sod(7^((r-1) % 3)))
 %970 = [1, 7, 4, 1, 7, 4, 1, 7, 4, 1, 7, 4]
```

After that we need the residue of the exponent $\;^37 \pmod 3$ which- since $7 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ is $1$.

So we have $$ \text{sod}(\;^47 ) = \text{sod}(7^{\;^37 \pmod 3} ) =\text{sod}(7^{1}) = 7 $$

---

***update***
To see, whether exactly 4-times iterated sum-of digits would arrive at a one-digit number I've estimated this using Pari/GP:
Here `nd_xxx` means "number-of-digits of xxx" , `sd_xxx` sum of digits of xxx. The sum is simply estimated by the average of the possible digits meaning `sd_XXX = 4.5 * nd_XXX`. Z is here $ \;^47$.

```
nd_Z=%59 \\= 7^7^7^*log(7)/log(10)   
 %85 = 3.17741949328 E695974   \\ number digits of Z

A=sd_Z=4.5*nd_Z
 %86 = 1.42983877198 E695975   \\ estimated sum of digits of Z  

nd_A=log(A)/log(10)            \\ number of digits of A
 %87 = 695975.155287

B=sd_A=4.5*nd_A                \\ est. sum of digits of A 
 %88 = 3131888.19879

nd_B=log(B)/log(10)            \\ est. number of digits of B
 %89 = 6.49580625035

C=sd_B=4.5*nd_B                \\ est. sum of digits of B
 %90 = 29.2311281266

nd_C=log(C)/log(10)            \\ est. number of digits of C
 %91 = 1.46584557655

D=sd_C=4.5*nd_C                \\ est. sum of digits of C
 %92 = 6.59630509448
```

So using the sum-of-digits recursively 4 times might arrive at a single digit number.

---

However, this answer might have missed the exact point of the question. I consider to delete it later.

Comment: Here you don't actually know how many times you repeat the process of doing the sod, and in the original problem, we must do it a precise number of times

Comment: @Andrej - ok, might be I've missed the focus of the question. I'll come back to this later, perhaps I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score -1):

$$
\begin{split}
7^{7^{7^7}}= 7^{7^{823543}} &= 7^\text{a number with around $>100000$ but less than $1000000$ digits}\\
&= \text{a number with around a number with 5 digits}
\end{split}
$$
Therefore, $C$ has $5$ digits